# Adjust element width to scrollbar in parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a card that has a bunch of text in it.  If the text is too large for the card I want to add a scrollbar.  The card also has a footer.  My problem is that I want the footer to shrink slightly if there is a scrollbar.  I don't want my footer to be present underneath the scrollbar.

[image]

In the actual application the footer is like the Microsoft Word ruler:

[image]

I can put the footer inside the `overflow-y` region but then it is no longer sticky (always visible).

Here is the code:

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#stickyFooter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="content">
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
  </div>
  <div id="stickyFooter"></div>
</div>
```

An ideal solution would be CSS/HTML and not require JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the footer inside the content and use `position:sticky` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#stickyFooter {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="content">
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLHAH</p>
    <p>end</p>
    <div id="stickyFooter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```